# javascript timezone script for United States how to do daylight saving

Tags: javascript, time, timezone-offset

I have a working script that I push out to everyone's IE favorites list in our organization (see below).  Depending on where the office is geographically in the company they get routed to 1 of 4 urls.

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
var today = new Date();
var offset = (today.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) + 1;
if (offset == 5) document.location.href = "url=EASTERNtime.com";
else if (offset == 6) document.location.href = "url=CENTRALtime.com";
else if (offset == 7) document.location.href = "url=MOUNTAINtime.com";
else if (offset == 8) document.location.href = "url=pacifictime.com";
else document.location.href = "url=pickyourowntimezone.com";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am wondering about is how Daylight Saving time is going to affect my script since I know we have offices in Arizona and they don't recognize it.  What would I need to change to my script to make sure people are still routed correctly?  I was thinking something like..

if date is between march 11th and November 4th run this...if not...run this...

Does that make sense?  Or do I even need to worry about this and it will all sort itself out when their clocks change or don't?

Answer (score 1):

My Date Extensions have methods to identify DST:

http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/

The *dateinstance*.isDST() method will return "true" if it appears that the date falls within local DST, "false" if not.

But the general idea is both really simple and mind-bendingly horrifying (since it's really just a dumb guess).  Basically wherever DST (or similar scheme) is used and whatever start and end dates are defined the time zone offset between January 1st will not be the same as July 1st.  Add in some code to honor the fact that the Southern Hemisphere does everybody backwards and wrong (I kid!) a simple function to determine any particular date (and the one used in my extensions) is:

```
        // isDST 
        // Returns "true" if the date appears to fall within the local area's Daylight Saving Time (or similar scheme), returns false if the date does not (or it appears that the region doesn't observe DST).
Date.prototype.isDST = function() { 

        // Generate test dates
    var Jan1 = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0);
    var Jul1 = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6);

        // DST in the Northern hemisphere is "fall back"
    if ( Jan1.getTimezoneOffset() > Jul1.getTimezoneOffset() && this.getTimezoneOffset() != Jan1.getTimezoneOffset() ){
        return true;
    };
        // DST in Southern hemisphere is "leap ahead"
    if ( Jan1.getTimezoneOffset() < Jul1.getTimezoneOffset() && this.getTimezoneOffset() != Jul1.getTimezoneOffset()){
        return true;
    };
        // We're not in DST 
    return false;
};
```

Solutions using the TZ Database are more robust in that they can determine which timezone is being used - but are often just as feckless when determining whether a time is in DST (due to the fact that the rules for start and end times are often in flux).

For your need, tho', I think that the above code should do the trick.

Comment: not sure how the above code would help me.  You are saying I need to enter a date to get DST to work but the date is different every year.  Its the first sunday in the month...so...how would that work?

Comment: You do have to have an example date for the function above to work.  The function tells you if a date (any date you like) falls within DST (or similar) in the region that the script is run.  In your case I assume it would be the current date.  You only care about where they need to be routed NOW, correct - not next year?  The code doesn't need to know EXACTLY when DST starts or ends - all it's doing is comparing the current date to a date when it knows there is NEVER DST.  If the date is the same, you're outside DST, if it's different you're inside DST.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty robust timezone detection script at http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript.  The unminified code is available at https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/src/e265c8eddec7/detect_timezone.js.

Comment: not sure how this will help me either as it uses dates that are hard coded.  right?  What I am hoping to do is setup a page that I won't have to touch or worry about for the next 5 years.

Comment: No, the dates that are hard coded are just test dates that are used to determine which timezone a user is in.  The only time they have to be updated is if a time zone actually gets redefined such that the current time zone isn't defined the same as it was in 2011 (which apparently happened in Minsk Belarus). The last time this happened in the US was 2007, previous to that was 1987.